# snow leopard: how to change left-to-right and right-to-left input?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-shortcuts

When i Open a text edit and i want to write some text. is there some kind of a keyboard shortcut to start writing from the right side of the page instead of the left ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable keyboard shortcuts in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Input Sources*
[image]